# $(x+y)\frac{dy}{dx} -(4x+y)=0, y(1)=2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Hi I am stuck solving this problem: 
'Employ a change of variables $z=\frac{y}{x}$ to solve the differential equation: $$(x+y)\frac{dy}{dx} -(4x+y)=0, y(1)=2$$

Enter the result $y(3)$.

I have done the substitution and then integrated by I cannot get an explicit expression for y, which leaves me confused as to how I can find $y(3)$. 
Please help!

Comment: The solution is $y(x)=2x$ but I only got this by inspection. Basically, I usually try some low-degree polynomials and noticed that $\pm 2x+c$ worked without the initial condition. With $c=0$ the condition is satisfied.

Comment: @QC_QAOA the implicit solution is much more complicated thats whay Op cant find $y(3)$. The solution has terms in $y-2x$ at some exponent...

Comment: Hi this is very nice of you. How were you able to 'guess' that the solution was of the form ax+b?

Comment: One of the first thing I do with ODEs is to try polynomials of various degrees (as well $e^{ax}$). I plugged in $ax+b$ and got that $a^2-4=0$ which implied $a=\pm 2$. This then implies $b=0$. Thus, the only solution can be $y(x)=2x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from

$$(x+y)\frac{dy}{dx} -(4x+y)=0$$

rewrite as

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4x+4}{x+y}=\frac{4+\frac xy}{1+\frac xy}$$

then with the substitution $z=\frac{y}{x}$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=z+x\frac{dz}{dx}$ so

$$z+x\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{4+z}{1+z} \implies x\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{4-z^2}{1+z}$$

which we can rewrite as

$$\frac{1+z}{4-z^2}dz=\frac{1}{x}dx$$

where a partial fraction decomposition of the LHS forms

$$\frac{1+z}{4-z^2}=\frac{-1}{4(z+2)}-\frac{3}{4(z-2)}$$

hence

$$-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}+\frac{3}{z-2}\right)dz=\frac{1}{x}dx$$

whereby integrating both sides forms

$$-\frac{1}{4}\Big(\ln|z+2|+3\ln|z-2|\Big)=\ln|x|+C$$
or
$$\ln|z+2|+3\ln|z-2|=-4\ln|x|+C$$
which can be rewritten as
$$(z+2)(z-2)^3=Cx^{-4} \implies C=x^4(z+2)(z-2)^3$$
therefore substituting $z=\frac{y}{x}$
$$C=x^4\left(\frac{y}{x}+2\right)\left(\frac{y}{x}-2\right)^3$$
the initial/boundary condition of $y(1)=2$ forms
$$C=1(4)(0)=0$$
hence since $x\neq 0$ we see that
$$(y+2x)(y-2x)^3=0$$
which implies
$$y=-2x,\quad y=2x$$
where $y=-2x$ cannot be the solution since $y(1)=2$. Therefore, $y=2x$ is the solution and $y(3)=6$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $z = \frac{y}{x}$ yields $y=xz$, and hence $\frac{dy}{dx} = x\frac{dz}{dx}+z$.
From this, we find by substitution
\begin{align*}
(x+xz)(x\frac{dz}{dx}+z) - (4x+xz) &= 0 \\
\text{ divide by } x, \text{ and simplify}\\
x \frac{dz}{dx} +z +zx \frac{dz}{dx} +z^2 -4-z &= 0 \\
\frac{dz}{dx}x(1+z) &= 4-z^2 \\
\frac{dz(1+z)}{4-z^2} &= \frac{dx}{x} \\
dz \left( \frac{3}{4(2-z)} - \frac{1}{4(2+z)} \right) &= \frac{dx}{x}
\end{align*}
Solving this differential equation, we get for some constant $K$,
$$\frac{1}{|(z+2)(z-2)^3|} = Kx^4.$$

Substituting $z = \frac{y}{x}$ again, we get after simplifying
$$ 1 = K|y^2-4x^2|(y-2x)^2 $$

Using the information that $y(1)=2$, we should be able to find $K$, but we get the following.
\begin{align*}
1 &= K|2^2-4 \cdot 1^2|(2-2 \cdot 1)^2 \\
1 &= 0
\end{align*}
Are you sure you copied the condition $y(1)=2$ correctly? There is definetily some mistake in your formulation of the problem anyway.

The next step would be to solve the polynomial equation
$$1 = K|y^2-4 \cdot 3^2|(y-2 \cdot 3)^2$$
Finding $y$ that fits this will then be the solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking your time to help me. I have copied the problem statement word for word but I also think there's a problem with it. I also encountered this problem with the initial condition. I will ask my teacher about this.

Comment: The condition y(1)=2 requires that the constant is zero and so we obtain

(y−2x)3(y+2x)=0

This means that either y=2x or y=−2x

The second solution does not satisfy the initial condition and so

y=2x